# Power Query wont import any access files

Tags: excel, ms-access, powerquery

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this, I had Microsoft office 2010 and 2013 on my machine. It was causing some problems where it was opening excel 2010 instead of 2013, so I uninstalled 2010. after I did so I have received this error when I try to connect to any access database.

"DataSource.NotFound: Microsoft Access: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.. The Access Database Engine 2010 Access Database Engine OLEDB provider is required to connect to read this type of file."

I am able to connect to other sources such as web files and excel files, but those are the only other files that I have tried to connect to.

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall Power Query; uninstall and reinstall office.

All Help will be appreciated.

Comment: The error message also contains an URL that you can copy and paste into the browser. This will take you to a site that lets you download the ACE driver.

Comment: Thank you, Im going to download the drivers and try again

Comment: that didn't work, I received an error saying that you don't have any version of this software installed on you machine, so I Installed the other one that was provided and received the same message.

Comment: If I recall correctly, there are separate links for the driver and for a service pack to the driver. Did you accidentally pick the service pack?
You'll need to pick a bitness to match the bitness of Office that you have installed.